# Ubuntu server minimal - символы в окнах

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сервер

Есть чистый VDS с дистрибутивом Ubuntu server minimal 14.04.

С английским я дружу, а вот окна из символов чисто эстетически напрягают. Это не только в MC, но и в других программах.

Или может кто то отговорит от идеи, если это тянет за собой кучу ненужного?!

Примеры:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
locale 

LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU.UTF-8" 
LC_TIME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
 LC_COLLATE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
 LC_MONETARY="ru_RU.UTF-8"
 LC_MESSAGES="ru_RU.UTF-8"
  LC_PAPER="ru_RU.UTF-8" 
 LC_NAME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
 LC_ADDRESS="ru_RU.UTF-8"
 LC_TELEPHONE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
 LC_MEASUREMENT="ru_RU.UTF-8"
    LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_RU.UTF-8" 
LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8
```

Comment: локаль нужно поменять на UTF-8/кирилица

Comment: приведите в вопросе вывод `$ locale`.

Comment: получилось локализовать MC, но tasksel и не которые другие по-прежнему отображаются символами

Comment: LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8

Comment: Редактировал с телефона, поехали отступы. Поправьте, кому это удобно. )

Comment: Пакет `console-cyrillic` установлен?

Comment: console-cyrillic пробовал устанавливать, но желаемого результата не принесло =(

Comment: Может дело в сборке дистрибутива? Вирут. OVZ. Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 2.6.32-042stab120.11 x86_64)